# Creating a lucky number guessing game (passing Arrays to functions/calling functions)

Tags: c

I've been having some trouble with a guessing game that populates an array with random integers, and then has the user try to guess a number in the array.  I believe I have most of it correct, but the program will not go beyond the "Initializing lucky numbers..." print command for me to check whether my functions are working or not.  I believe the problem either lies with how I'm passing the array to the functions, or how I'm calling the functions (perhaps in their prototypes?)  Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
This is my first post, so I apologize if I was unable to correctly include the code.  Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/*
This program is a lucky number guessing game. A series of unique, random numbers 
will be generated and stored in an array. Users will have up to three chances to
guess a number stored in the array.*/

//Function Prototypes
int fillArray (int,int []);
int searchArray (int, int []);
int printArray (int, int []);

int main(){
 const int MAX = 25;
 int iArray[MAX]={0};
 int count;

 printf("Initializing lucky numbers...");
 //printf("%d", iArray[0]);
 //for(count=0;count<MAX;count++){
   //printf("%d ",iArray[count]);
 //}//end for loop
 fillArray(MAX,iArray);
 //ONLY TO CHECK ARRAY CONTENTS
 //printf("%d",iArray[0]);
 //for(count=0;count<MAX;count++){
 //  printf("%d ",iArray[count]);
 //}//end for loop
 //CARRY ON WITH PROGRAM
 searchArray(MAX,iArray);

 getch();
 return 0;   
}

//Function Definitions

//Fill Array Function
int fillArray(int max,int Array[]){
    int i;
    int j;
    int uniqueFlag;
    int random;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
     /* Assume things are unique... we'll reset this flag if not. */
     uniqueFlag = 1;
     do {
        random = (rand() % 101);
        /* This loop checks for uniqueness */
        for (j = 0; j < i && uniqueFlag == 1; j++) {
           if (Array[j] == random) {
              uniqueFlag = 0;
           }//end if statement
        }//end for loop
     } while (uniqueFlag != 1);
     Array[i] = random;
}//end while
//ONLY TO CHECK ARRAY CONTENTS
printf("%d",Array[0]);
printf("\n%d\n",Array[1]);
for(i=0;i<max;i++){
  printf("%d ",Array[i]);
}//end for
}//end function

//Search Array Function
int searchArray(int max, int Array[]){
    int i;
    int guessCounter=0;
    int iGuess;
    do{
       printf("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: ");
       scanf("%d",&iGuess); 
       for(i=0;i<max&&guessCounter<3;i++){
          if(Array[i] == iGuess){
              printf("Correct");
              guessCounter = 3;
              }//end if
          else{
               printf("%d is not one of the lucky numbers.\n",iGuess);
               guessCounter++;
               }//end else
               }//end for
    }while(guessCounter < 3); //end do-while loop
    if(guessCounter==3){
        printf("Sorry! You lose!\n");
        printArray(max, Array);
        }//end if
}//end function   

//Print Array Function
int printArray(int max, int Array[]){
    int i;
    printf("Array contents: ");
    for(i=0;i<max;i++){
       printf("%d ",Array[i]);
    }//end for
}//end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniqueFlag` needs to be reset whenever you pick a random number, not just at the start of the outer loop in `fillArray`.

Comment: Thank you. My looping skills are still a little weak, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! For anyone checking up, or having similar problems, I've included my corrections. I was able to check for unique numbers in a separate function called checkArray, and resolved my fillArray issue by returning a pointer from the fillArray function, along with a few other (included) tweaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


//Function Prototypes
int fillArray (int, int []);
int checkArray (int, int, int []);
int searchArray (int, int []);
int printArray (int, int []);

int main(){
 const int MAX = 25;
 int iArray[MAX]={0};
 int count;

 printf("Initializing lucky numbers...\n");
 fillArray(MAX,iArray);
 searchArray(MAX,iArray);

 getch();
 return 0;   
}

//Function Definitions

//Fill Array Function
int fillArray(int max, int Array[]){
int number;
int i=0;
int uniqueFlag;
srand(time(NULL));

while(i<max){
     number = (rand() % 101);
     if(checkArray(max, number, Array)==0){ //passes to another function to check for uniqueness
          Array[i]=number;
          ++i;
     }//end if
}//end while
return *Array;
}//end function

//Check Array Function
int checkArray(int max, int number, int Array[]){
int i;
int uniqueFlag;
for(i=0;i<=max;i++){
     if(Array[i]==number){  //determines if random number has already been used in array
          uniqueFlag = 1;
          return uniqueFlag;
     }//end if
     else{
          uniqueFlag = 0;
     }//end else
}//end for
     return uniqueFlag;
}//end function

//Search Array Function
int searchArray(int max, int Array[]){
int i;
int x=0;
int guessCounter=0;
int iGuess;

while(x !=1 && guessCounter<3){
       printf("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: ");
       scanf("%d",&iGuess);
       for(i=0;i<max;i++){
            if(iGuess==Array[i]){
                 x = 1;
                 }//end if
       }//end for
       switch(x){
          case 1:
               printf("%d is one of the lucky numbers. Congratulations! You win!", iGuess);
               printArray(max, Array);
               getch();
               return 0;
          default:
               printf("%d is not one of the lucky numbers.\n",iGuess);
               ++guessCounter;
          }//end switch statement
          }//end while condition
if(guessCounter==3){   //condition limits to 3 guesses per run
          printf("Sorry! You lose!");
          printArray(max, Array);
          }//end if   
}//end function

//Print Array Function
int printArray(int max, int Array[]){
int i;
printf("\nArray contents: ");
for(i=0;i<max;i++){
   printf("%d ",Array[i]);
}//end for
//getch();
//return 0;
}//end function
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to see whether `searchArray` has a problem at a first glance, so you should simplify it. I suggest moving the whole `uniqueFlag` portion out to its own function, `doesArrayContain` maybe?

Comment: Ah, thank you. That's excellent advice. Breaking this into simpler portions to finish/check made this a lot easier!

Comment: Sorry, I meant "fillArray". Proper indentation and more generous whitespace usage will also help avoid mistakes such as this one I've made. Not to mention the "//end function" comments...